# How do you get HTML5 inputs to validate if they are inside Polymer Web Components?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I am using Polymer Web Components and my application targets Chrome.  On my form, outside the Web Components I have an input type='number', when I enter 'a' into the input and submit the form, I get a tooltip that says "Please enter a number."

However, I have another input type="number" that is in the Shadow DOM of a web component.  When I enter 'a' into that field and submit the form, I get no tooltip.  Is there anyway to make the behavior more consistent?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing the same problem you describe (using Chrome 36 and Polymer 0.3.3). The form validation works as expected with the following simple Polymer element ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/modede/2/edit)):

```
<polymer-element name="test-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <form>
      <label>Inside the element:</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Numbers only!">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**EDIT**: In the examples you've shown, your host page's `<form>` is separated from the Polymer element's `<input>` due to the [shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) boundary. Is there a reason you're structuring things that way?

It doesn't look like any `<input>`s that exist in the shadow DOM actually get submitted along with a light DOM `<form>`, so the fact that they're not being validated is in a sense expected and the least of your concerns. (Take a look at the Network trace for [this example](http://jsbin.com/sotaqire/6/edit) and you'll see that only `test=1234` gets submitted.)

Taking the approach in the example above and including the `<form>` in the Polymer element is enough to get the expected validation behavior that modern browsers offer. Alternatively, if all you really want is `<template>` and you don't need a full blown Polymer element, you could do something along the lines of ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sotaqire/3/edit)):

```
<form>
  <template is="auto-binding">
    <label>Inside the element:</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Numbers only!" value="{{myNumber}}">
  </template>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  document.querySelector('template').myNumber = 34;
</script>
```

That works too, because once the `<template>` is bound, the contents are added directly to the page's DOM like any other element.

If you strongly that you can't refactor your code as described, then I think you'd need to address your concern via bugs against the web browsers in question and see if they have any willingness to start considering `<input>` elements in the shadow DOM as part of a light DOM's `<form>`.

Comment: <code>
    <form>
      <polymer-element name="test-element" noscript>
        <template>
          <label>Inside the element:</label>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Numbers only!">
        </template>
      </polymer-element>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
</code>

This shows the error.